# Cannot run gimp on macbook

Tags: mac, macbook, gimp, macports

Downloaded gimp via macports onto a Macbook Pro running OS X Yosemite (10.10.5).  In the ton of output from macports, I saw no obvious problems.  I tried to run without success, however.  It just tells me "Cannot open display:"  Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the native version? http://www.gimp.org/downloads/

Comment: @Michael Frank  I figured macports would make for easier installation.  Surprise!  Surprise!  Any experience with the native version?  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used it in a long time unfortunately.

Comment: It's the only supported version, anyway.

Comment: If anyone's interested, downloaded the native version and it works just fine.  No idea what the problem is with macports.